# Live streaming using Wamp

Tags: wamp

i am using Wamp to make my PC as a server and i want to record a video using my camera and live stream it to other mobiles.

i have searched about the code to do it using wamp and i can't find it.

anyone can help me  to do it using Wamp?

Comment: Wamp is an HTTP server with PHP support and a MySQL installation, geared for developers, and nothing more. You're better off using a dedicated tool for this job, since writing an application from scratch is not trivial. [Start with this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=stream+webcam+from+pc+to+phone). Modify it to look for e.g. the mobile device you want to stream to (e.g. android vs. iphone, etc.). Start by looking for solutions to your actual problem. You will be lead down a difficult path if you assume Wamp is the solution from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/demo) to be a fitting technology, although setting it up might be more difficult than expected. There are a lot of WebRTC hosting providers that have popped up, but you would be spending money and using their service. Have you thought of setting up a simple [justin.tv](http://www.justin.tv/) or [ustream](http://www.ustream.tv/) instead of hosting it yourself?